# FormView doesn't update but creates new record of model

Tags: python, django

I'm using class-based views.

I'm using a FormView, but open to change to UpdateView if necessary.

My main goal is that after I access my `List` (name of Model) I can change its name if desired.

URL that accesses a particular List, inside user should see all elements related to that particular list and can update its name using a form.

```
path('lista-detalles/<int:lista_id>/', views.ListDetailsFormView.as_view(), name='list_details'),
```

Currently my `ListDetailsFormView` doesn't update but creates a new record.

**models.py:**

```
class List(models.Model):
    LISTA_STATUS = (
        ('recibida_pagada', 'Recibida y pagada'),
        ('recibida_no_pagada', 'Recibida pero no pagada'),
        ('en_revision', 'En revision'),
        ('en_camino', 'En camino'),
        ('entregada', 'Entregada'),
        ('cancelada', 'Cancelada')
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Lista anónima')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school = models.OneToOneField(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LISTA_STATUS, default='recibida_no_pagada')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_at']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404, get_object_or_404
class ListDetailsFormView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    form_class = ListForm
    template_name = "scolarte/listas/lista-detalles.html"

    def get(self, request, lista_id, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        lista = get_object_or_404(List, id=lista_id)
        data_dict = {'name': lista.name,}
        form = ListForm(initial=data_dict)
        context['form'] = form
        list_items = ListItem.objects.filter(lista=lista)
        context['list_items'] = list_items
        total = 0
        for list_item in list_items:
            total += Decimal(list_item.sub_total())
        context['total'] = total

        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def form_valid(self, lista_id, form):
        # instance = get_object_or_404(List, id=lista_id)
        # form = ListForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
        # form = form.save(commit=False)
        # form.user = self.request.user  
        # form.save()
        form.instance.name = self.request.name
        form.save()
        return super(ListDetailsFormView, self).form_valid(form)


    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('lists:list_details', kwargs={'lista_id': self.kwargs['pk']})
```

**BONUS:** I'd like to return to the same page, the one that shows the current List and its items.

**UPDATE 1:**

I've made use of UpdateView, but still the form creates a new objects instead of updating.

View:

```
class ListDetailsFormView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = List
    form_class = ListForm
    context_object_name = 'lista'
    pk_url_kwarg  = 'lista_id'
    template_name = "scolarte/listas/lista-detalles.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['list_items'] = ListItem.objects.filter(lista=self.object)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.name = self.request.name
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('lists:list_details', kwargs={'lista_id': self.object.pk})
```

**HTML:**

```
{% extends 'scolarte/base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<!-- <h1>Mi lista: {{ lista.name }}</h1> --> 


<div class="row">
    <form action="{% url 'lists:my_lists' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>



<div class="row">
    {% for list_item in list_items %}
        {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 and not forloop.first %}<div class="w-100"></div>{% endif %}
        <div class="card margin-right3" style="width: 14rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{ list_item.product.short_name }}</h5>
              <p class="card-title">$ {{ list_item.product.price }}</p>
              <p class="card-text">{{ list_item.description }}</p>
            </div>
        </div> 
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

After updating the FORM HTML, I'm getting:

```
AttributeError at /listas/lista-detalles/14/
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'name'
```

**html:**

```
<div class="row">
    <form action="{% url 'lists:list_details' lista.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to pass the instance when you create the form, but that being said, you can eliminate a lot of boilerplate by using an `UpdateView`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem could you provided a working example, pls.

Comment: @OmarGonzales Django is well documented. Why don't you search the doc first ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Acoording to this: `https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/` I only need to do `self.object = form.save()` in `form_valid`. But that still creates a new object. Answer from Willem, help a bit, but still creates a new object.

Comment: @OmarGonzales I was talking about Django's documentation. Things like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) for example.

Comment: Looks like you're not posting to the right url...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `instance` when you create the form, but that being said, you can eliminate a lot of boilerplate by using an [**`UpdateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview):

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView

class ListDetailsFormView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = List
    form_class = ListForm
    context_object_name = 'lista'
    pk_url_kwarg  = 'lista_id'
    template_name = "scolarte/listas/lista-detalles.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['list_items'] = ListItem.objects.filter(lista=self.object)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.name = self.request.name
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('lists:list_details', kwargs={'lista_id': self.object.pk})
```

It however looks like your `ListForm` has a `name` field, in that case, you do not need to override the `form_valid` method at all, and you this can use:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView

class ListDetailsFormView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = List
    form_class = ListForm
    context_object_name = 'lista'
    pk_url_kwarg  = 'lista_id'
    template_name = "scolarte/listas/lista-detalles.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['list_items'] = ListItem.objects.filter(lista=self.object)
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('lists:list_details', kwargs={'lista_id': self.object.pk})
```

Comment: Got this: `Generic detail view ListDetailsFormView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.`

Comment: @OmarGonzales: yes, you need to specify the `pk_url_kwarg` here, since it is not `'pk'`

Comment: this still creates a new object, instead of updating the current one. In my original question, I already had: `form.instance.name = self.request.name` on `def form_valid(self, form)`

Comment: @OmarGonzalez: It should normally *edit* the item for which the primary key is the one you pass through the `lista_id` primary key.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem are you sure you want to keep the `form.instance.name = request.name` line in `form_valid()` ?

Comment: @OmarGonzales did you forget to make your view an UpdateView instead (as in Willem's snippet) by any chance ?

Comment: @OmarGonzales: you should make the POST request to the *same view* (so the updateview), not some other view.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem please. see Update 2.

Comment: @OmarGonzales: that is because by default a `request` object has no `name`. Exactly what are you aiming to do with `form.instance.name = request.name`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem change the original name of the List object, if User wants to do so.

Comment: @OmarGonzales: but that is already handled by the `ModelForm`. This is what `form.save()` will do. So then you do not need to override `form_valid` at all.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it works now, Thank you. In question: In my template I have `{{ lista.name }}`, but I don't see `lista` being passed in the context. Howcome I can use that variable? . I just see this: `context_object_name = 'lista'`. Would you explain this, pls?

Comment: @OmarGonzales: because we set `context_object_name = 'lista'`, and A Django view with a `SingleObjectMixin`, will pass the object to the template under that name.